# как с помощью localStorage сделать так чтобы теги <p> создаваемые в JavaScript не исчезали после перезагрузки? без jQuery

Tags: button

js

```
function fuf() {
    let ghj = document.querySelector('body');
    ghj.innerHTML += "<p>приветик</p>";
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="fyf()">
    <button onclick="fuf()">кликЕР</button>
    <p id="loshok"></p>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В твоём варианте это будет жестко :)

Сохранять - вот так...

```js
localStorage.setItem("saved",
  JSON.stringify([...document.querySelectorAll("body p")]
    .map(el => el.innerText)
  )
);
```

Читать - вот так...

```js
let savedParagraphs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saved")) || [];
savedParagraphs.forEach(text => {
    let newElement = document.createElement("p");
    newElement.innerText = text;
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
});
```

В чём прикол... В localStorage можно хранить только строки! Поэтому массив надо сохранить как JSON и потом прочитать как JSON. Если прочитать не удалось, то результат getItem == null. JSON.parse(null) будет null и если результат null то `null или пустой_массив` - `|| []` вернёт пустой массив. Потом обходим (если был) каждый элемент по словам и создаём параграф - (не вот так `ghj.innerHTML += "<p>приветик</p>"`) что в корне не правельно, а правильно через создание DOM элемента параграф, и установкой ему текстового значения. Потом присоеденяем новый созданный элемент к тэгу BODY у которого есть символическая ссылка `document.body`